# Linq query where there's a certain desired relationship between items in the result

Tags: linq

A `linq` query `Where` clause can apply a `func` to an item in the original set and return a `bool` to include or not include the item based on the item's characteristics. Great stuff:

var q = myColl.Where(o => o.EffectiveDate = LastThursday);

But what if I want to find a set of items where each item is related to the last item in some way? Like:

```cs
var q = myColl.Where(o => o.EffectiveDate = thePreviousItem.ExpirationDate);
```

How do you make a `Where` (or other `linq` function) "jump out" of the current item?

Here's what I tried, trying to be clever. I made every item an array just so I can use the `Aggregate` function:

```cs
public IQueryable<T> CurrentVersions
{
  get => AllVersions
         .Select(vo => new T[] { vo })
         .Aggregate((voa1, voa2) => voa1[0].BusinessExpirationDate.Value == voa2[0].BusinessEffectiveDate.Value ? voa1.Concat(voa2).ToArray() : voa1)
         .SelectMany(vo => vo);
}
```

but that doesn't compile on the `SelectMany`:

> The type arguments for method `Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,
>   TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>>)`
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

**EDIT (SOLUTION)**

As it turns out, I was on the right track, but was just confused about what `SelectMany` does. I didn't need it. I also needed to change `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` because I'm using EF and you can't query after you let go of the `DbContext`. So, here is the actual solution.

```cs
public IEnumerable<T> CurrentVersions
{
  get => AllVersions
         .Select(vo => new T[] { vo })
         .Aggregate((voa1, voa2) => voa1[0].BusinessExpirationDate.Value == voa2[0].BusinessEffectiveDate.Value ? voa1.Concat(voa2).ToArray() : voa1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq queries are most effective when each item is processed in isolation. It doesn't work well when trying to relate items within the same collection, without having to process the same collection multiple times and standard linq operators.

The [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) library helps provide additional operators to fill in some of those gaps.  I'm not sure what operators it provides that could be used in this instance, but I know it has a `Pairwise()` method that combines the current and previous items in the iteration.

In general, for situations like this, if you needed to roll out your own, it would be far easier to write it using a generator to generate your sequence. Either as a general purpose extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereWithPrevious<TSource>(
            this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Func<TSource, TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var iter = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iter.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        var previous = iter.Current;
        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
            var current = iter.Current;
            if (predicate(current, previous))
                yield return current;
        }
    }
}
```

or one specifically for the problem you're trying to solve.

```
public static IEnumerable<MyType> GetVersions(IEnumerable<MyType> source)
{
    using (var iter = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iter.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        var previous = iter.Current;
        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
            var current = iter.Current;
            if (current.EffectiveDate == previous.ExpirationDate)
                yield return current;
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative approach which while standard practice in other languages but terribly inefficient here would be to zip the collection with itself offset by one.

```
var query = Collection.Skip(1).Zip(Collection, (c, p) => (current:c,previous:p))
    .Where(x => x.current.EffectiveDate == x.previous.ExpirationDate)
    ...;
```

---

And with all of that said, using any of these options will most likely make your query incompatible with query providers.  It's not something you would want expressed as a single query anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about zip and skip but until you see it you can't visualize it to type it out. And by the time the set is whittled down to this function, it's only a few rows of data. So the inefficiency doesn't impact much.

Comment: > Install-Package "System.ValueTuple" -IncludePrerelease

Comment: You could also just use an anonymous object in place of the tuple.

Comment: Actually, this turned out to be almost but not quite the best solution because I needed the "previous" to be in the complete time line. See my solution edit. Thanks!